# Как удалить сигналы виджета gtk+?

Tags: c, gtk

Функция `g_signal_handler_disconnect ( gpointer instance,gulong handler_id);` требует id обработчика,я задолбался с `g_signal_handler_find()`, поэтому решил удалить ВСЕ сигналы, как это сделать??

Comment: Проблема XY? я бы предложил запомнить id сигнала, который возвращает `g_signal_connect*()` и просто использовать его... если нет, то `g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched ()`, но это по сути тот же `g_signal_handler_find()` только выполняющий дисконнект...

Comment: @Fat-Zer,в `g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched ()` куча непонятных параметров, что где передать, чтобы удалились все сигналы?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, можете разобрать каждый параметр?

Comment: @Fat-Zer,`g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched(G_OBJECT(people_profile.Button),0,0,0,NULL,0,data);` - не работает, возвращает 0

Comment: по параметрам, основных два: `instance` — объект у которого искать обработчики сигналов, `mask` — что именно искать, функцию, замыкание, данные, id сигнала, и т.п. этот параметр является битовой маской, т.е. задаётся в виде типа `G_SIGNAL_MATCH_FUNC|G_SIGNAL_MATCH_DATA`... Все остальные параметры почти всегда не используются... осмысленное значение задавать им нужно только если соответствующий флаг в `mask` установлен... например, если в mask есть `G_SIGNAL_MATCH_FUNC`, то нужно задать `func`, если `G_SIGNAL_MATCH_CLOSURE|G_SIGNAL_MATCH_DATA`, но `closure` и `data` и т.п...

Comment: По поводу `g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched()` я ошибся — с её помощью все обработчики сигналов отсоединить не получится... ей в `mask` нужно передавать хотя бы один из флагов `G_SIGNAL_MATCH_CLOSURE`, `G_SIGNAL_MATCH_FUNC` или `G_SIGNAL_MATCH_DATA`... Какого-до разумного способа убрать все обработчики сигналов я в API не вижу, так что похоже единственным способом будет `g_signal_handler_find`+`g_signal_handler_disconnect` в цикле ... Но, повторюсь, желание удалить все обработчики сигналов виджета звучит очень странно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, огромное спасибо! Написали бы как ответ, помечу как правильный

Comment: мм... не... вопрос всё равно не понятно о чём, так что не вижу особого смысла писать на него ответ... можешь сам написать, если хочешь...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ну как не понятно о чем , вы же ответили на него, я все понял, остаётся только переписать ваши комментарии в ответ

Comment: вопрос сформулирован сильно странный, а комментарий отвечает ИМХО на другой вопрос, так что оформление всего этого в ответ мало что даст SO, как базе знаний... а всё что я хотел высказать с целью помочь я уже уместил в комментариях... так что обе причины писать ответ для меня ушли...